# Django cannot find my inherited comment form

Tags: django

Am trying to modify the look of django comments template form on my site but in vain.

I have created a comments folder on my project template folder(myproject/template/comments/) and copied the **form.html & preview.html** from django/contrib/comments/template/comments/).

I have then modified my local comment form.html according to my needs.

On the template that i want to insert the comment i have added the following code

```
<h2> Enter your comments </h2>
{% load comments %}
{% render_comment_form for myObject %}
```

When i call the form, the comment form never gets rendered, just a blank page with the title **Enter your comments**

its like django is not seeing my local form, because when i try to insert some text in the local **form.html** i don't see anything?!

What am i missing

Gath

Comment: Can you post your entire `form.html`? It should contain all the code in the original (or at least a viable replacement) - original available at http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/form.html

Comment: True! i think i screwed up something...while copying the original form.html. Thanks, let me try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to your bespoke `comments` templates in your settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS? If not, Django will fall back to the templates in the django.contrib.comments package.

Comment: Yes folder is in the TEMPLATE_DIR